# Precedence of post and pre incrementation operators

Tags: c++, operators

There is code:

```
#include <iostream>

class Int {
public:
    Int() : x(0) {}
    Int(int x_) : x(x_) {}
    Int& operator=(const Int& b) {
        std::cout << "= from " << x << " = " << b.x << std::endl;
        x = b.x;
    }
    Int& operator+=(const Int& b) {
        std::cout << "+= from " << x << " + " << b.x << std::endl;
        x += b.x;
        return *this;
    }
    Int& operator++() {
        std::cout << "++ prefix " << x << std::endl;
        ++x;
        return *this;
    }
    Int operator++(int) {
        std::cout << "++ postfix " << x << std::endl;
        Int result(*this);
        ++x;
        return result;
    }
private:
    int x;

};

Int operator+(const Int& a, const Int& b) {
    std::cout << "operator+" << std::endl;
    Int result(a);
    result += b;
    return result;
}

int main() {
    Int a(2), b(3), c(4), d;
    d = ++a + b++ + ++c;
    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
++ prefix 4
++ postfix 3
++ prefix 2
operator+
+= from 3 + 3
operator+
+= from 6 + 5
= from 0 = 11
```

Why postfix operator isn't executed before prefix operator (++ prefix 4) altough priority of postfix operator is higher than prefix operator?

This was compiled by g++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The order of evaluation of the different operands is unspecified which means that the compiler is free to reorder the evaluation of the `++a`, `b++` and `++c` subexpressions as it pleases. The precedence of the operators does not really have any impact in that example.

It does have an effect if you try to write `++i++` (where `i` is an `int`) which will be grouped as `++(i++)` and it will fail to compile as the subexpression `i++` is an rvalue and prefix increment requires an lvalue. If the precedence was reversed, then that expression would compile (and cause Undefined Behavior)

Comment: it would not reorder `++a`, `b++` and `++c` but their evaluation since it is independent.

Comment: I have compiled such statements ++a++ + (++b)++ and there was no error. For class in example it works, but for types like int it doesn't:  error: lvalue required as increment operand

Comment: @Benoit: Right, I started the sentence with that, but then forgot to make it explicit where it most matters.

Comment: @scdmb: Yes, I should have been more precise. In this case, because it is a user defined type that offers the operations both expressions compile and are well-defined, but in the case of fundamental types as `int` the comment stands: `int i = 0; ++i++;` fails to compile, `int i = 0; (++i)++;` is undefined behavior. In the case of user defined types, `++i++` will result in a call to the post-increment followed by a call to the pre-increment, proving the precedence of the operators, right?

Comment: So why (++i)++ is undefined behavior? Shouldn't it be like: increase i by one, return reference of i, do i++? It seems to be quite ok.

Comment: @scdmb: For an `int i`, it is undefined behavior because (in C++03 parlance) the integer is modified twice within an expression without any intervening sequence points. I would have to review the C++11 standard, as the whole *sequence point* terminology is gone... As to an example where it might go wrong... in that particular example it is hard to find an ordering of the operations that might cause different outcomes, but the standard would allow for it.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: C++11, 1.9p15. *If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either another side effect on the same scalar object or a value computation using the value of the same scalar object, the behavior is undefined.* So `i=i+++1;` is still UB, just like before.

Answer (score 0):

Postfix `++` has the highest precedence in the expression `++a + b++ + ++c`, but `+` has the lowest precedence and is left associative. This expression can be equivalently written as `(++a) + (b++) + (++c)` (each `++` is part of a different subexpressions) which explains why `++a` is evaluated first. Consider traversing/evaluating the corresponding parse tree and it becomes obvious what the order of evaluation:

```
           E
         / | \
        /  |  E
       /   |  | \
      E    +  ++  c
    / | \
   /  |  \
  E   +   E
 / \     / \
++  a   b  ++
```